# PHP populate html select with array from function

Tags: php, dropdownbox, invalid-argument

OK, so, this may seem like a dumb question.  I've looked through the other threads with this thing and I'm not finding QUITE what I'm looking for.

I get this error:

> Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in entry.php on line 118

line 118 is the foreach that I'm using here:

```
<select id="Location" name="Location" class="text">
<option selected="selected"> - Choose Location - </option>
<?php 
    $locations = getLocationList();//this returns an array from separate function
    foreach($locations as $location) {//<-Line 118
        echo "<option value=". $location['locationID'] .">".$location['locationName']."</option> ";
    }
?>
</select>
```

It's not populating, it's only throwing the error.
Thoughts?

OK **EDIT**
This is how I'm pulling the data in a separate function:

```
function getLocationList()
{
    $mydb = new myDBC();//<-this calls my secure connection class
    $table = "LocationTable";
    $sql = "SELECT `locationID`, `locationName` FROM " .$table;
    $rez = $mydb->runQuery($sql);//<-this connects runs my query
    if(isset($rez))
    {
        $newRow = mysqli_fetch_array($rez);//<-is this not returning an array?
        return $newRow;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does a var_dump of $locations tell you? Does it really returns an array or maybe a null value?

Comment: It's not returning anything - which means, it's probably not pulling the data correctly...?

Comment: make sure that you are connected to the database if you are getting data from a database and also check the getLocationList() as if it is empty it means that it is not returning anything

Comment: Ok, so I went and changed the way it was pulling, and when i do a var_dump I get only one location out of 12 `array(4) {
  [0]=>string(1) "1"
  ["locationID"]=> string(1) "1"
  [1]=> string(7) "Atlanta"
  ["locationName"]=>string(7) "Atlanta"
  }`

Comment: To me, it sounds like your method `getLocationList();` is all messed up. Provide the code for this function so we can inspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have errors like `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` it literally means that whatever variable you are using in your `foreach()` is not an array nor an object. Verify that `$locations` is either an array or an object. One you fix that, it would work.

Ok, after checking your update, try making these changes:

Change this:

```
if (isset($rez)) {
    $newRow = mysqli_fetch_array($rez); //<-is this not returning an array?
    return $newRow;
}
```

To this:

```
if (isset($rez)) {
    return $rez->fetch_assoc();
}
```

---

OK, seems like your class/library is not a full library and because of this you have to add your own code to enhance it. In order to make this work how you would like it to, add this function somewhere in your DBClass.php

```
function convert_result_to_arr($result) {
    if ($result) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $arr[] = $row;
        }
    }
    return $arr;
}
```

This will convert your results into an appropriate muilti dimensional array so that you can iterate and get your info.

Now you can use it like this:

```
$rez = $mydb->runQuery($sql); //<-this connects runs my query
$rez_converted = $mydb->convert_result_to_arr($rez);
if(isset($rez_converted )){
        return $rez_converted ;
}
```

Now you can iterate like you originally wanted to:

```
foreach($locations as $location) {//<-Line 118
        echo "<option value=". $location['locationID'] .">".$location['locationName']."</option> ";
    }
```

I would also highly recommend that you transition into an MVC framework. I recommend Codeigniter to start. You wouldnt need to worry about all this along with other problems that come along.

Comment: now that the data is being pulled appropriately, I get this info: Illegal string offset 'locationID' in entry.php on line 120 which is my echo statement.

Comment: probably because you are not getting an array. What do you get when you `var_dump($location);` ?

Comment: hang on... I'm going to show you how i'm pulling the data in the original post...

Comment: is `myDBC` a custom library? if so, where can we find the documentation?

Comment: Yes, this is my connection class - which also runs my queries

Comment: I found it online a few months ago.  I think it's on github.  I will see if I can find it.

Comment: So you made it up? You would need to show us the code for that. Specdifically for this method `$mydb->runQuery($sql);`

Comment: I don't think I can post it here with this question, can I?  Should I send it to you?

Comment: wait. Try one more thing. I will post it on my answer

Comment: I get:`<select id="Location" name="Location" class="text">
 <option selected="selected"> - Choose Location - </option>

 <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'locationID' in <b>entry.php</b> on line <b>121</b><br />
 <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'LocationName' in <b>entry.php</b> on line <b>121</b><br />
 <option value=1>1</option> <br />
 <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'locationID' in <b>entry.php</b> on line <b>121</b><br />
 <br />
 <b>Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'locationName' in <b>entry.php</b> on line <b>121</b><br />
 <option value=A>A</option>
</select>`

Comment: I'm on it.  willbe sending from my gmail (mb2000inc).

Comment: This works. Though, The first record is repeated once - other than that, it's great.

Comment: weird that you get that extra one. That shouldnt be the case. Let me know if you still need help with this.

Comment: Heh, I got it.  I had an extra one in the DB

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a `print_r()` or `var_dump()` of `$locations`. There's nothing wrong with your foreach loop, so most likely the `getLocationList()` function is returning a non-array, or an empty array.

Befor `foreach()` you can check `count($locations)`

```
    <?php 
    $locations = getLocationList();//this returns an array from separate function
    if(count($locations)>0)
    {
        foreach($locations as $location) 
        {
              echo "<option value=". $location['locationID'] .">".$location['locationName']."</option> ";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Have to tried to put `foreach` in `if(count($locations)>0) { }` ?

Comment: I get this info: `Illegal string offset 'locationID' in entry.php on line 120` which is my echo statement

Comment: Paste the result of `print_r($locations);`

Comment: `array(4) {
  [0]=>string(1) "1"
  ["locationID"]=> string(1) "1"
  [1]=> string(7) "Atlanta"
  ["locationName"]=>string(7) "Atlanta"
  }`

Comment: This is `var_dump()` result. Please paste `print_r()` result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80596/discussion-between-user1151316-and-mark-bogner).